# How to retrieve multiple let linq to xml c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get all the Hoop attributes but its only getting the first values(In this instance it is adding 24 and 4 to the listbox). Is there a way of adding all my result to a list. I usually use .ToList() but it did not work in this instant. The aim was to get the hoops for Home and away separate then store it into an object.

XML:

```
<League>
  <Round>
    <Match>
      <Team Side="Home" >
        <Hoop qtr="1st" player-name="Joe" time-scored="24" />
        <Hoop qtr="1st" player-name="Jack" time-scored="54" />
      </Team>
      <Team  Side="Away">
        <Hoop qtr="1st" player-name="James" time-scored="4" />
        <Hoop qtr="1st" player-name="Brown" time-scored="34" />
      </Team>
    </Match>
  </Round>
</League>
```

C#:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var query = from q in xDoc.Descendants("Team")
            where (string)q.Attribute("Side") == "Home"
            let d = q.Element("Hoop")
            select new
            {
                Period = d.Attribute("qtr").Value,
                Name = d.Attribute("player-name").Value,
                Time = d.Attribute("time-scored").Value
            };
foreach (var qq in query)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(qq.Time);
}
```

Comment: "it did not work" is *far* too vague - what happened? (My guess is it failed because there's no `time-scored` value in your XML, but you really need to clarify that. Either that, or it failed because you're looking for an attribute called `side` and it's actually `Side`.) Also, please ensure you indent both code and XML appropriately - it makes a huge difference in readability.

Comment: Spelling and capitolization are very important.  Make sure all those things match.  Next, looking for things that aren't there can cause failures.  Make sure those things match.  Finally, if the issue is that you're getting 1 record where you expect 2....that's an entirely different kind of failure, and you should specify that as well.

Comment: Thanks Jon. It did not fail it is currently displaying only the first hoop time for both the Home and Away Team. I would like to receive all the hoop time dynamically so if there is 7 hoop element in the home team it will add all 7 hoop time to the listbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `let d = q.Element("Hoop")` to `from d in q.Elements("Hoop")`

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var query = from q in xDoc.Descendants("Team")
            where (string)q.Attribute("Side") == "Home"
            from d in q.Elements("Hoop")
            select new
            {
                Period = d.Attribute("qtr").Value,
                Name = d.Attribute("player-name").Value,
                Time = d.Attribute("time-scored").Value
            };
foreach (var qq in query)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(qq.Time);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew.